# async Lambda invocation from Api Gatway with parameters

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an Api Gateway GET method called /tasks/{tasktype}

It's pointed to a Lambda function with the X-Amz-Invocation-Type set to 'Event'

Then in my Lambda I have this

```
public void FunctionHandler(Object input, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        LambdaLogger.Log($"GOT: {input.ToString()}");   
    }
```

This all works fine, except input is null.

Is there any way I can pass through and access the value of {tasktype} from the Api Gateway?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass them in using either a mapping template or check the box for "Use Lambda Proxy integration".

Mapping Template reference:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html

Proxy Integration reference:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html

Comment: Thanks. What should be the type for "request" when it's custom integration not proxy?

public string FunctionHandler(APIGatewayProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext context)
{

}